# Вывод из БД в вью с ограничением по дате/времени

Tags: python, база-данных, django

Добрый день.
Есть модель с объектами и полем дата/время zakaz_time
Нужно вывести данные по всем объектам, которые были заведены в определенный период.

```
zakazs = Zakaz.objects.all()
```

шаблон

```
Общее кол-во заказов: zakazs|lenght
Кол-во за день: ???
Кол-во за месяц: ???
Кол-во за год: ???
```

django 1.8   python 3.4

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#date. `zakazs.filter(zakaz_time__date=datetime.date(2015, 12, 11).count()`. Вообще, почитайте ссылку целиком (между 1.8 и 1.9 отличий немного и там они указаны).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если имеется в виду текущий день, текущий месяц и текущий год, то:

Для начала вам понадобится получить текущий день:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
```

Получим все заказы:

```
zakazs = Zakaz.objects.all()
```

Получим общее кол-во заказов:

```
zakazs_total_count = zakazs.count()
```

Получим кол-во заказов за сегодня:

```
zakazs_day_count = zakazs.filter(zakaz_time=today).count()
```

Получим кол-во заказов за текущий месяц:

```
zakazs_month_count = zakazs.filter(zakaz_time__year=today.year, zakaz_time__month=today.month).count()
```

Получим кол-во заказов за текущий год:

```
zakazs_year_count = zakazs.filter(zakaz_time__year=today.year).count()
```

Comment: спасибо, для работы zakazs_month_count = zakazs.filter(zakaz_time__year=today.year, zakaz_time__month=today.month).count()  требуется установка pytz